# Data normalization for linear regression

Tags: regression, normalization, lognormal-distribution

I'm currently writing my thesis on the comparison of ultrasound measurements with DEXA scan measurements for specific fat distributions (40 participants). I would like to perform a linear regression to look into the relationship between my variables. I'm working with SPSS. 
I checked for normality and according to Shapiro Wilk, 3 variables appear to be not normally distributed. I checked for the skewness of these variables and 1 of them showed obvious skewness, I transformed the data of this variable using a log10 and checked for normality again, which was good now. The other 'not normally distributed' variables on the other hand were not really skewed and transforming them with log10 dit not help to meet normalization assumptions according to Shapiro Wilk. 
Is there any way I can still get these variables to distribute normally or do I have no choice than to perform non-parametric statistics, Spearman correlation in my case?
I looked on the internet but I couldn't find an answer for my specific question, I hope there is anyone that can help.

Comment: Hi Karen. You do not need the predictor variables to follow a normal distribution in a linear regression, you expect the predictor to have a linear relationship with the response, and the residuals are normally distributed

Comment: What I don't quite get from your question is, what actually is the final goal or aim, is it to explore the relation between the variables you are measuring? Or do you have a response in mind, and are looking for what can explain this variable of interest?

Comment: Thanks for replying. So the aim of the study is to validate Ultrasound (new method) by also using DXA (already known method). I'm trying to validate ultrasound by looking at the correlation between an antropemetric measurement (for example BMI) and Ultrasound and comparing it with the correlation between that same antropometric measurement (BMI) and DXA. By comparing these 2 correlations, I can somehow compare DXA and Ultrasound.

Comment: I think you helped me out already. I was checking the normality for the variables independantly, but as you stated, it have to be the residuals of the 2 variables that have to distribute normally. I just checked this in SPSS and it seems they do, so I can now run my linear regression. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Arh good, glad it works out for you ! Yeah I guess if it works, you can just compare the correlation

Comment: can't you directly compare DXA to ultrasound? or is BMI measured in some other way important to your research?